# Can I disable Windows 7's indexing/scanning of dvd contents?

Tags: windows-7, performance, dvd

When I try to copy data from a DVD on my Windows 7 machine, I keep running into this problem. I open the DVD drive in windows explorer to browse the files, select the ones I wish to copy then paste them onto any hard drive or network location.
The file copy progress information window pops up and starts calculating the time remaining etc.

This is the moment when Windows 7 decides it absolutely MUST index the file contents of my DVD. The address bar starts to display that little green background progress bar that I've come to understand means "I'm currently very busy doing busy things with your busy disc"..
This means that the dvd drive has to support two concurrent read operations, which makes performance go down the toilet.. (from ~8MB/s to ~1MB/s)

Exactly what it is indexing for I'm not sure. It could be the windows search service, but the problem still persists despite me having disabled the service. 
I also entertained the notion that it could be scanning files in order to create thumbnails, and checking 'Always show icons, never thumbnails' in folder options seems to have shortened the time Windows 7 takes to scan the dvd somewhat, not fully though.

Is there any other reason for Windows to scan my DVD drive that I have missed? Can I disable the scanning at all?

Comment: test like this.  Select all the files you wanted, select copy, close anything that was viewing the dvd, then paste. That should stop the normal file scanning of any open directory, providing another clue.

Comment: Maybe explorer is trying to generate thumbnails or your antivirus software is check the files. The copy handler will list necessary files before the copying to avoid this very problem...